# Discord.py: Is it possible to use one cogs function into another cogs?

Tags: python, discord.py, lavaplayer

Hello I just want to use the async module on the first cogs into another by so that the code wont be too long for a single file and maximize the code reuse:

Module_cogs_1.py :

```
class Music_base(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    # this is the module that to be imported

    async def insert_player_song(self, ctx, track, track_index):
        player = self.bot.lavalink.player_manager.get(ctx.guild.id)
        player.add(requester=ctx.author.id, track=track, index=track_index)
```

Module_cogs_2.py :

```
class Module_test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.command(aliases=['test'])
    async def test_track(self, ctx, track_index :typing.Optional[int]=0, *, query:str):
    # accessing the async module from Module_cogs_1.py
    await Music_base.insert_player_song(self, ctx, track, track_index)
```

If imported locally i can used as `await self.insert_player_song()` but when i try to import outside or in second file without self on the argument `await Music_base.insert_player_song(ctx, track, track_index)`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vee/sauce-v3x/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/vee/sauce-v3x/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/vee/sauce-v3x/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: insert_player_song() missing 1 required positional argument: 'track_index'
```

But when adding the self onto the argument `await Music_base.insert_player_song(self, ctx, track, track_index)`

```
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vee/sauce-v3x/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/vee/sauce-v3x/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 863, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/vee/sauce-v3x/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Music_base' object has no attribute 'guild_queues'
```

I hope you can understand guys and thank you so much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-static methods can't be called without an instance of the class.

You should be able to get the created instance of the class using [`bot.get_cog`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_cog#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_cog) passing the name of the Cog.

Then you can use that instance to call the method.

```
music_base = self.bot.get_cog("Music_base")
music_base.func(ctx, ...)
```

If it is a command you want to run, you can also get the command with `bot.get_command`, store it in a variable, and execute it as a function.